# How to override Model file ConvertToCsv in custom module

Tags: model, export, override-model

Here am trying to override a vendor file that is

`vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php`

`etc/di.xml` file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="Pravendor\PRA\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" />
</config>
```

overridden file path

`app/code/Pravendor/PRA/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php`

```
<?php
namespace Pravendor\PRA\Model\Export;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv as ConvertToCsvParent;
/**
 * Class ConvertToCsv
 */
class ConvertToCsv extends ConvertToCsvParent
{
    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directory;
    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;
    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $pageSize = null;
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $productHelper;
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $timezone;
    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param MetadataProvider $metadataProvider
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Filter $filter,
        MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        Product $productHelper,
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        $pageSize = 200
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
        $this->pageSize = $pageSize;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        parent::__construct($filesystem, $filter, $metadataProvider, $pageSize);
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }
    public function getCsvFile()
    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PRAcsv.log'); 
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); 
        $logger->info('Your text message'); 


        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();


        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';

        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();
        $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
        //exit(get_class($dataProvider));
        $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);

        $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();

        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        $i = 1;
        $searchCriteria = $dataProvider->getSearchCriteria()
            ->setCurrentPage($i)
            ->setPageSize($this->pageSize);
        $totalCount = (int) $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getTotalCount();
        while ($totalCount > 0) {
            $items = $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getItems();
            //  echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_class($dataProvider)); exit;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if($component->getName()=='sales_order_grid') {
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($item->getEntityId());
                    $items123 = $order->getAllItems();
                    $skuArray = [];

                    foreach ($items123 as $key => $item1) {
                        $skuArray[] = $item1->getSku();

                    }
                    $export_status = implode(", ", $skuArray);
                    $item->setSku($export_status);
                }
                $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
                $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
            }
            $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage(++$i);
            $totalCount = $totalCount - $this->pageSize;
        }
        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();

        return [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ];
    }

}
```

but file is not overridden, where am doing wrong. can I get help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `di.xml` file in adminhtml instead of global.

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml

and run below command

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Thank you so much @Gohil Rajesh, its successful override.

Comment: great !! happy to hear